# file access protected by .htacess file didn't take password stored in .htpsswd file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration-files, server-configuration

I have tried it in Magento root

```
AuthUserFile /home/username/public_html/.htpsswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"

<files "index.php" >
    Require valid-user
</files>
```

I tried to protect access  index.php file by .htaccess file by above code

I find base path on **AuthUserFile** by php code

```
<?php
echo getcwd();
 ?>
```

Here's my .htpsswd file

```
admin:admin
```

Everytime I enter password it show popup which ask for password again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work perfect, it was mistake in  file name (spelling) ..

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens when the password is incorrect. Change the contents of your .htpasswd file to:

```
admin:$apr1$ol.jlx5P$ldshyeA.03GTKJWGFgQYH/
```

Now you should be able to log in using:
username: admin
password: admin

If that doesn't work, Check and make sure the path to your .htpasswd file is correct.

Comment: it was file name mispelled.